# Map canvas missing from QGIS project

Tags: qgis

I opened a project that I've been working on for a year. The layers are loaded but the map canvas is missing.
Instead the map canvas window shows the option to start a new project from template.

This is only for this project, other projects open fine.

I run QGIS 3.20.0 on Windows.

I've tried zoom to layer etc, but there is no active map window at all for this to help.

Is there a fix or do I have to start a new project and load in all layers again?

Comment: Do you see anything if you go to View -> New Map View?

Comment: I believe I have the same problem. New Map Vies does not help. Also, I am not able to open Attribute Table on any of the layers.